# How do I show the attachment on inbox list in email by sending PHP mail

Tags: php, email

I have this code :

```
$to = $input['to'];
    $from = $input['from'];
    $subject = $input['subject'];
    $message = $input['message'];
    $file = $input['file'];

    $filename = 'Invoice.pdf';

    $content = file_get_contents($file);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

    $separator = md5(time());

    // carriage return type (RFC)
    $eol = "\r\n";

    // main header (multipart mandatory)

    $headers  = "From: testsite.com < admin@testsite.com >\n";
    $headers .= "Cc: ".$from."\n"; 
    $headers .= "X-Sender: testsite < admin@testsite.com >\n";
    $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 1\n"; // Urgent message!
    $headers .= "Return-Path: testsite\n"; // Return path for errors
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol;

    // message
    $body = "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol;
    $body .= $message . $eol;

    // attachment
    $body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"" . $filename . "\"" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol;
    $body .= $content . $eol;
    $body .= "--" . $separator . "--";

    mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

This code already working and already have attached when you read the email. But what's missing is this:

[image]

This is the example I wanted to see in inbox list. Thanks you!.

Comment: I'd use a free library such as PHPMailer which makes this kind of task much simpler and less error-prone Why re-invent the wheel? Someone has already gone through all the pain for you.

Comment: the question is, does this solve the issue above?

Comment: More than likely, because it will make it easy to write code which will attach a file correctly.